# get friends facebook mobile fb.ui hello world

Tags: facebook-graph-api, mobile, fb.ui

I am working on a facebook mobile web app. There is the following function.

```
function getUserFriends() {
    FB.api('/me/friends&fields=name,picture', function(response) {
        console.log('Got friends: ', response);

        if (!response.error) {
            var markup = '';

            var friends = response.data;

            for (var i=0; i < friends.length && i < 25; i++) {
                var friend = friends[i];

                markup += '<img src="' + friend.picture + '"> ' + friend.name + '<br>' + friend.id + '<br>';
            }

            document.getElementById('user-friends').innerHTML = markup;
        }
    });
}
```

When  it returns the pictures are missing.
The console log returns:

```
[06:02:12.503] GET http://m.mochirestaurant.com/fb/%5Bobject%20Object%5D [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 77ms]
```

While it should return something like:

```
http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/276211_285403872_5043326_q.jpg
```

I think I misconfigured something in my facebook app but don't know what it is

Answer (score 0):

> [06:02:12.503] GET http;//m.mochirestaurant.com/fb/%5Bobject%20Object%5D [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 77ms]

Instead of a real value you can see that it says `[object]` in there (with the brackets URL-encoded) – which is what browsers return when you are trying to bring an object into a string context. (And because that is not a full URL beginning with http://…, your browser treats it as a relative address and tries to request it from *your* domain.)

So obviously `friend.picture` at this point in your code is not a string value, but an object.

(So far for the debugging and spotting-the-error-part.)

This stems from the [October 3, 2012 Breaking change](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) regarding the user/picure connection,

> **/picture connection will return a dictionary when a callback is specified**
>
> We will start returning a dictionary containing the fields url, height, width, and is_silhouette when accessing the /picture connection for an object and specifying a callback property. Currently we just return the picture URL as a string.

So you have to use `friend.picture.url` in your code to get the actual string property containing the user picture’s URL.